# Gnome Tweak Tool does not save changes

Tags: ubuntu, xfce

### Gnome Tweak Tool

Faced such problem, installed The gnome Tweak Tool utility through the terminal 
`sudo -i *password*`
`sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool`
 
everything is set, all the hood, opened the program via `' sudo gnome-tweak-tool`
And then the problem itself began, that I would not change in this program, I do not change anything,what could be the problem, maybe you need to somehow apply these changes, but how? Maybe you need to put priority to this program through the terminal, I should just Xfce, in fact he's got his editor.
Then everything changed,simply by selecting from a list, but in gnome tweak tool. Whatever I change, nothing applies.

> If it helps, I have a Xubuntu distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you install the right version of gnome-tweak-tool which correspond to your gnome version.
Check this out:
https://pkgs.org/download/gnome-tweak-tool